# I cant install Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: installation, 12.04

First, sorry for my bad English. I can't install Ubuntu. When i boot CD, and select language, and press Install Ubuntu, than everything sto responding, and after 5 minutes I get some green letters and some error, but I can't understand it, you cant see it good... I have preinstaled Windows 8 Consumer preview, but free (not formated) drive for ubuntu. Please help.

Comment: You should probably try the alternate CD if the normal one crashes (you can find it at http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads)

Comment: can u put some error also..

Comment: @jP_wanN, that could be an answer more than a comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you have problems with the standard CD, just use the [alternative CD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads).

Answer (score 0):

If you have already installed Windows, I advise you to install Ubuntu using wubi, which included in Ubuntu's live CD, by open the CD directly using Windows Explorer and choose wubi.exe
But, if you want to install the grub, maybe you must give free space or a partition to format in your hardisk for installing ubuntu first.
In your case I think the problem is on your CD or CD reader, so you must try it once again.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Wubi installs Ubuntu within windows. Since the user wants to use a separate partition, this is surely not an option. Thanks for the opinion, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing off a Live USB.

> Using a USB drive?
>
> Most newer computers can boot from USB. You should see a welcome screen prompting you to choose your language and giving you the option to install Ubuntu or try it from the CD.
>
> If your computer doesn’t automatically do so, you might need to press the F12 key to bring up the boot menu, but be careful not to hold it down - that can cause an error message.

From: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-desktop

You can use Unetbootin or Pendrive for this.

> Installing Unetbootin is very easy. You can download the 4MB unetbootin.exe and give it permission to execute as program and then make a shortcut to it. No further work necessary. Next thing you can do is to install Ubuntu in USB flash drive. You might need to change the BIOS setting to boot from USB.

From @Curious Apprentice, [How can I install Ubuntu if my computer doesn't boot from the CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134145/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-if-my-computer-doesnt-boot-from-the-cd/134154#134154)

Pendrive: [How to Install Ubuntu 12.04 with Pendrivelinux?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129901/how-to-install-ubuntu-12-04-with-pendrive-linux)